# Existing play application, should I add my Actor system and actor API to it?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Here is the current scenerio:

1. I have an existing web application that is using play
2. I need to create an actor system with a http interface that will re-use some libraries in #1

In order to simplify development (not having to start multiple processes during development etc), I was thinking to add my actor system + http interface to my existing play application like:

```
http://localhost:8080/akka/api/....
```

I believe I can create a separate akka thread pool inside of the application.conf.

**Production configuration:**

Now when I push to production, since my play application will run on multiple web servers, I would have a configuration flag which would enable or disable the akka system in my play application.
Now I can deploy my akka service to single server (or more in the future) by enabling it in the configuraiton, and in the other regular www services I would disable it.

*Is this a good idea, will it work?
If so, how could I enable/disable the akka part of it using a simple flag in my configuration?*

From what I have seen, people normally start the akka system from inside of a controller, maybe I can do it in the onStart stage and if the akka-flag is disabled just skip it during startup?

Comment: I don't know about what people normally do but I wouldn't be starting in a controller. If you want to use your own Akka system in play you can initialise it in the Global.scala onStart function.

Comment: If you want different config on different nodes you can use environment variables or pass different options on the command line. See bottom of https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production

Comment: @LionelPort that is the easy part, but how can I turn off my custom akka code.  If I simply don't instantiate the actorSystem that is enough?

Comment: the shared code is that separated out ? Are you forced currently to re-use current app?

Comment: @Barry I'm not forced, I have a multi-project sbt setup.  But I just want to simplify things if possible, don't want to run 2 apps when developing.